# IE10 aborts image downloads

Tags: javascript, html, image, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

I am trying to cache a couple hundred fairly large images (each image is about 2000x2500, 350KB) for display in a web application. My basic process is to create an Image object for each, set its src, and wait for it to download. Then use the Image object to load the image when needed by the application.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var countSpan, errorSpan;
    var imageArray = new Array();

    var index = 0;
    var imageCount = 199;
    var concurrent = 4;

    var count = 0;
    var error = 0;

    function runTest() {
        countSpan = document.getElementById('countSpan');
        errorSpan = document.getElementById('errorSpan');
        next(); 
    }

    function next() {
        while (index < imageCount && concurrent > 0) {
            downloadImage('images/' + index + '.jpg', index);
            index++;
        }
        countSpan.innerHTML = count;
        errorSpan.innerHTML = error;
    }

    function downloadImage(src, index) {
        concurrent--;
        var image = new Image();
        imageArray[index] = image;
        image.onload = function() {
            concurrent++;
            count++;
            next();
        }
        image.onerror = function() {
            concurrent++;
            error++;
            next();
        }
        image.src = src;
    }
</script>
</head>

<body onload='runTest()'>
    <p>Downloaded: <span id='countSpan'></span></p>
    <p>Errors: <span id='errorSpan'></span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

This works great in Firefox, Chrome, Safari, and IE9.  However, IE10 will abort the connections about half way through.  For example, if I attempt to download 200 of these images, IE10 will download 100 (~35MB of data) then error out on the remaining 100.  The Network capture tab shows the connections as Aborted.  I see the iexplore.exe process open TCP connections, then immediately close them when the images begin to error out.

If I attempt to download 200 smaller images (640x480, ~45KB) it works.

If I don't hold on to the reference to the Image

```
// imageArray[index] = image;
```

IE10 downloads all 200 images.  But this defeats the purpose.

It seems to me that IE10 has a size limit on Image references.  But I cannot find any documentation to support this.  If you can provide a link to the documentation defining this limitation or provide a workaround it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think this would affect anything, but I'm just wondering - why are you adding them to the DOM and then removing them. You should be able to cache them by simply using `new Image()` and then reusing them by putting them in the array. Does that not work?

Comment: Also, it's a dumb idea, but what if you split up `imageArray` into 3 arrays that hold 90 each. Again, I doubt that's a problem, but it's an idea

Comment: Hey Ian.  Thanks for the ideas.  You are of course correct about not needing to add the images to the DOM.  However, in my 'real' application I was having issues with IE not correctly reporting the image width and height unless I did.  I removed these calls (code updated above) but the problem persists. I will play around with splitting up the arrays as well.  I'm willing to try anything at this point.

Comment: No dice splitting up the Array either...

Comment: @BJ_ I am facing exact same issue with almost similar code. And it doesn't work for ma either. did you find any solution for this?

Comment: I opened a ticket with Microsoft, https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/783078/image-downloads-are-aborted  They basically said it's fixed in IE11 and thus will not be fixed in IE10.